# Query String spaces

Tags: html, post, request, query-string

I was wondering how to write a Query String in a POST HTTP form request if occur some space (I guess the problem would occur in case of GET form request too) . 
I am going to make an example:

If I have for example a value "English (US)" would the Query String (for example) in a hypothetic log in form be:

```
username=value1&password=&language=English (US)
```

I mean would be language=English (US) correct with the space inside?

And one more question. Since I have to use "password", would the query string be sent like this "password=&"? Or must I write something between "password=" and "&"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are using Query string params on a POST.  Usually you would just include all values in the post body.  Also, it is not a good idea to send credentials as query parameters.  An HTTP AUTH header is a better choice if you don't have a more secure option.

Nonetheless, if you use the JavaScript encodeURIComponent() function, it will properly encode the spaces.

If you are using jQuery $.ajax() calls on a GET and provide the values as the 'data' option, then jQuery will call encodeURIComponent for you.

Comment: Thank you. But I am writing by hand, in order to make some exercise for an exam. Unfortunately I will be obliged to write by hand and not using a computer and that's why I was asking how to write it properly :)

Comment: Replace the spaces with %20

Comment: Many thanks! And what about "password=&"? Browser wouldn't be able to read what is writing, so how would be created the query string with a password inside?